# How can I get an object with multiple parameters in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am creating database objects based on my CSV file.
My model is like this:

```py
class StockPriceData(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organization, verbose_name=_("Organization"), on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    s_n = models.IntegerField(_("S.No."))
    group_long = models.CharField(_("Group Long"), max_length=100)
    group = models.CharField(_("Group"), max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField(_("Date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    ...
```

I'm bulk creating the objects with a script which is as follows:

```py
for record in read_file:
        if count==1:
            pass
        else:
            
            # print(org)
            try:
                object = StockPriceData.objects.get(org__symbol=record[3])
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                org = Organization.objects.get(symbol=record[3])
                print(org)
                StockPriceData.objects.create(org=org, s_n=record[0],group_long=org.group_long,group=org.group,date=record[4],
                conf=record[5],open=record[6],high=record[7],low=record[8],close=record[9],vwap=record[10],vol=record[11],
                prev_close=record[12],turnover=record[13],trans=record[14],diff=record[15],range=record[16],diff_pct=record[17],
                range_pct=record[18],vwap_pct=record[19],year_high=record[20],year_low=record[21])
        count += 1
```

In my CSV file, one org__symbol has different dates and I want to check whether the symbol exists within that date.
When I try to do something like this:

```py
object = StockPriceData.objects.get(org__symbol=record[3], date=record[[4])
```

It says invalid syntax. What is wrong here? Can someone explain in easy words?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/scripts/stock_price.py", line 20, in run
    obj = StockPriceData.objects.get(org__symbol=record[3],date=record[4])
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
finance.models.DoesNotExist: StockPriceData matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 65, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/email_notifications.py", line 77, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/utils.py", line 62, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 283, in handle
    run_script(script_mod, *script_args)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runscript.py", line 161, in run_script
    exit_code = mod.run(*script_args)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/scripts/stock_price.py", line 23, in run
    org = Organization.objects.get(symbol=record[3])
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/anjaan/project/fintech/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 415, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
finance.models.DoesNotExist: Organization matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Please include the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: added the stack trace.

Comment: Your query fails to find a match, and causes an error. `finance.models.DoesNotExist: StockPriceData matching query does not exist.`

Comment: Yeah if it fails then it should execute the except: function right? Why it is not doing so?

Comment: You should use `get_or_create()` here and not `get()`. This will also mean you will not have to have the `try` clause. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Comment: Actually to add here. Your exception was handled, yet it raise another query issue `finance.models.DoesNotExist: Organization matching query does not exist`. Your get in your `except:` fails.

Comment: When I use get_or_create() it fails too

Comment: @Anjaan, That means your object does not exist in database. Have you checked your object through the admin interface? What type are the values of `record[3]` and `record[4]`?  Share also your `Organization` model.

Comment: I found the mistake, It was on the database. Thank you for your time.